# Limit the number of Active Directory connections while doing multiple requests

Tags: powershell, active-directory

My reconciliation scripts loop over lots of Active Directory users to disable them, remove their groups in certain containers, etc.

The Active Directory -Credential parameter used for e.g. Get-ADUser, Remove-ADGroupMember, etc. uses a Non Personal Account (NPA).

Our event monitoring team sees millions of connections by this NPA over the last few months.

My question: How can I limit the number of connections to AD? Can I open a connection, do all my queries and the close the connection (similar to SQL)? Can I create a shared connection object? Other tips to optimize this?

I now call Get-Credential in each loop because the script is updating multiple environments. Could it be useful to only call Get-Credential once for each environment and reuse the credential?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look up the use of `PSSession`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pssessions?view=powershell-7.3 ...and yes you should only need to request credentials once for each domain.
Unless you post the script there's not much other help I can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I find the AD cmdlets, while easy, are not efficient. If you want speed and connection sharing, you're better off using the .NET [`DirectoryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry) and [`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher) types, which have their own [type accelerators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_accelerators) in PowerShell: `[adsi]` and `[adsisearcher]`, respectively.

It gives you far more control of efficiency and speed, including taking advantage of [connection caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/connection-caching).

See these articles for examples on using them in PowerShell:

- [Working with Active Directory using PowerShell ADSI adapter](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4231.working-with-active-directory-using-powershell-adsi-adapter.aspx)
- [Use the PowerShell [adsiSearcher] Type Accelerator to Search Active Directory](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-the-powershell-adsisearcher-type-accelerator-to-search-active-directory/)

You'll also run into examples here on StackOverflow too.